# Allow to kill mounhelper to all users

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users, user-permissions, kubuntu

I have some machines with kubuntu 20lts, everyday when the machine start and the user's login, smb4k mount shares. But sometimes some shadows didn't mount because mountheper hungs. I need to allow all users to execute the kill command in a bash script to remote them All shares
My /etc/sudoers is
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /use/bin/kill
But it doesn't work... -bash: kill: (1709) - operación no permitida
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `sudo kill` needs to be used. but also take a look onto https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-running-sudo-command-without-a-password/

Comment: With the way that you have it, the user(s) or group would have to be specified in the sudoers file at the beginning of the line with the command. Do you have that?